# how do i integrate $ \sin(z^4)/z^4 $ over the unit circle?

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

how do i integrate $ \sin(z^4)/z^4 $ over the unit circle?

I cannot use cauchy's integral formula since $|z|=1$ and the singularity is at $z=0$ which is not *inside* the circle.

Is there a way i can integrate this using residues?
Thanks.

Comment: Hint: $\dfrac{\sin z^4}{z^4}$ is an entire function.

Comment: oh yes, you are right. I wrote $ sin(z^4)/z^4$ as a serie and then i integrate on the unit circle term by term  since it is holomorphic.  so it equals zero? am i right @G.Sassatelli

Comment: $0$ is inside the unit circle the last time I checked

Comment: @zhw. yes lol you are right. major fail on my part. So that means i can use cauchys integral formula, but the sin(z^4) is kind of confusing me, because that would mean i would have f(z^4) instead of f(z) in my cauchy integral formula.

Answer (score 1):

Is there really a singularity?  Look at what happens as $z\rightarrow0$, perhaps by using the Maclaurin series for the sine function.

That being said, technically the function should be written $\operatorname{sinc}(z^4)$.